# Java library (GSON) : NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, gson

For a project, I need to import the GSON library, despite of these steps found on different topics, I still have the error `NoClassDefFoundError`...

Step 1 : in the *BuildPath*, I add the library as an external JARs

Step 2 : in *Order and Export*, I check the library

So, if anyone has the solution, thank you in advance for your answers ! ;)

More Informations :

[image: Buildpath]
[image: Projectstructure]

```
package ummisco.gama.webgl;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class SceneReceiver {

private final static SceneReceiver instance = new SceneReceiver();

private boolean canReceive = true;

public static SceneReceiver getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

private SceneReceiver() {
}

public void receive(final SimpleScene scene) {
    reception(false);
    try {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String sceneSend = gson.toJson(scene);
        System.out.println(sceneSend);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    reception(true);
}

private void reception(boolean canReceive) {
    this.canReceive = canReceive;
}

public boolean canReceive() {
    return canReceive;
} 
}
```

Here the stacktrace :

```
Exception in thread "Thread-14" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson 
    at ummisco.gama.webgl.SceneReceiver.receive(SceneReceiver.java:28)
    at ummisco.gama.opengl.scene.ModelScene.endDrawingLayers(ModelScene.java:232)
    at ummisco.gama.opengl.scene.SceneBuffer.endUpdatingScene(SceneBuffer.java:74)
    at ummisco.gama.opengl.JOGLRenderer.endDrawingLayers(JOGLRenderer.java:713)
    at msi.gama.outputs.display.LayerManager.drawLayersOn(LayerManager.java:182)
    at ummisco.gama.opengl.SWTOpenGLDisplaySurface.updateDisplay(SWTOpenGLDisplaySurface.java:168)
    at ummisco.gama.ui.views.displays.LayeredDisplayView$11.run(LayeredDisplayView.java:673)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.Gson cannot be found by ummisco.gama.opengl_1.7.0.qualifier
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: How are you running it? Do you have a stacktrace that we can look at?

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace

Comment: To avoid these errors in the future, try to adopt a good dependency management system like  [maven](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/maven-tutorials/) / [gradle](http://www.mkyong.com/gradle/gradle-create-java-project-structure-automatically/). Anyways as mentioned, stacktrace would be helpful.

Comment: From where do you run this program. Ensure that JVM is able to find the library in its classpath.

Comment: Assuming you are running through Eclipse. Also, since this is an external jar, I would suggest adding it to the runtime 'class path' as well. You could check Run - > Run Configurations -> Classpath

Comment: The stacktrace is added to the post ! ;)
I'm running it with a ".product" file, it's a 8 years old project, I'm new on it, so :/

Comment: Thank you @BalajiKatika ! I add the gson library in my _MANIFEST.MF_ / ClassPath and it works ! ;D